# Svelte-Motion with SvelteKit SSR doesn't work with initial animation values

Tags: css, svelte, sveltekit, framer-motion

I have a SvelteKit SSR build, and in dev my intro animations seem to work, but when deployed, they initially start visible with no animations, and then they disappear and perform the animation. How do I fix this? I've pored over the documentation and issues and SO, and I can't find any resources on this issue.

Some sample code:

```
<div class="grid lg:grid-cols-2 justify-between items-center py-[6rem] max-w-[1200px] m-auto">
  <Motion initial={{ opacity: 0, x: 100 }} animate={{ opacity: 1, x: 0 }} transition={{delay: .25}} let:motion>
    <img use:motion class="p-5 m-auto hover:scale-[105%]" src="/images/home-responsive-devices.jpeg" alt="Homepage on different devices"/>
  </Motion>
  <Motion initial={{opacity: 0, y: 20}} animate={{opacity: 1, y: 0}} transition={{delay: .5}} let:motion>
    <div use:motion class="flex flex-col w-full">
      <p class="leading-8 px-10 py-6 text-justify"><span class="font-semibold">TEST</span> test</p>
      <a class="m-auto" href="/contact"><button class="self-center mt-10 btn btn-primary btn-outline">Learn More</button></a>
    </div>
  </Motion>
</div>
```